# Parameters passed in CloudPagesURL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl

Is there a list of the standard parameters that are passed when using the `CloudPagesURL` function? [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) passes information in an encrypted query string so it's difficult to determine the parameters. I have tested and know of a few parameters:

- `_subscriberkey`
- `emailaddr_`
- `JobId`
- `ListId`
- `memberid`

Any others parameters that I may have missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say most (if not all) of the [**Email, Email Date, Subscriber, and Sender personalization strings**](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/)  are included -- as are any attributes or data extension column names passed over in the send context.  That is as long as you're using the [**CloudPageURL**](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl) function to arrive at the page from an email.

```
+--------------------+
| Email Date Strings |
+--------------------+
| xtmonth            |
| xtmonthnumeric     |
| xtday              |
| xtdayofweek        |
| xtyear             |
| xtshortdate        |
| xtlongdate         |
+--------------------+

+-----------------------+
| Email Data Strings    |
+-----------------------+
| emailname_            |
| _emailid              |
| _messagecontext       |
| _replycontent         |
| _IsTestSend           |
| jobid                 |
| _JobSubscriberBatchID |
| _PreHeader            |
| _DataSourceName       |
| _listname             |
+-----------------------+

+-------------------------+
| Subscriber Data Strings |
+-------------------------+
| emailaddr               |
| firstname_ or firstname |
| lastname_ or lastname   |
| subscriberid            |
| _subscriberkey          |
| listid                  |
| list_                   |
| listsubid               |
| _messagetypepreference  |
+-------------------------+

+---------------------+
| Sender Data Strings |
+---------------------+
| replyname           |
| replyemailaddress   |
| memberid            |
| member_busname      |
| member_addr         |
| member_city         |
| member_state        |
| member_postalcode   |
| member_country      |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: How about business unit id(mid)? In case we need it to un-subscribe at business unit level?

Comment: `memberid` was in my original post