# Marketing Cloud CloudpageURL() link not reading data from data extension for added records in the Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio, smart-capture

We have an email linked to a CloudPage that has a smartcapture feature. The DE that is used for the email contains customer info which is exposed to the Cloudpage via ampscript:

```
%%[
var @emailaddress,@FirstName
set @emailaddress = AttributeValue("emailaddress")

set @emailaddress = Lookup("VisaAcquiDeJuly","emailaddress", "emailaddress", _subscriberKey )

set @FirstName = Lookup("VisaAcquiDeJuly","FirstName", "emailaddress", _subscriberKey )
]%%
```

Everything works fine and custom URL strings show for each customer, but if I add a new record to the original DE (Contact Builder > Add Record), their data doesn't get passed to the cloudpage when clicking the email's Link to Cloudpage button, and there is no custom URL string that shows up when redirected. How may I get the cloudpage working for new records?

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lookup logic looks strange. You are both passing email address in your cloudpagesurl as an Attribute, and looking it up in VisaAcquiDeJuly based on subscriber key (which also seems to be the email address)?

Normally, I would just use email address which is automatically included as a parameter in CloudPagesURL (without you need to add it explicitly), as per this answer: [Parameters passed in CloudPagesURL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262553/parameters-passed-in-cloudpagesurl)
This will make your solution much cleaner:

```
%%[
var @FirstName
set @FirstName = Lookup("VisaAcquiDeJuly","FirstName", "emailaddress", AttributeValue("emailaddr"))
]%%
```

You must add the new record to the Data Extension, with a value in emailaddress column, which matches the subscriber key of the email preview/send which you are testing.

Comment: Thank you Lukas! I was able to figure out that the CloudPageURL didn't work only when accessing it via the Preview. But when opening a test send, everything works fine. As for the logic, I've changed it to a more succinct version like you've put and it works all the same. The initial logic was just pulled from stringing together many resources from Elliot Harper's Amscript Guide to other Q&As on StackExchange.