# Marketing Cloud, Decode qs URL Parameter in Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl, decrypt

I am creating a Cloudpage in Marketing Cloud that is meant to grab the 'qs' URL parameter, decrypt it, and parse the response to show attributes like email address, etc. of the subscriber.

I am unclear on the process of Decrypting the qs parameter. I am using RequestParameter function like: `RequestParamter("qs")`

Do I need to use the DecryptSymmetric function to decrypt the parameter? If so, what is the corresponding encryption method, and what should my @DecryptionKey value be?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Using CloudPagesURL and AttributeValue functions as advised. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to apply explicit decryption method on QS. When linking to a Cloud Page using CloudPagesUrl function, email address and [other parameters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262553/parameters-passed-in-cloudpagesurl) are automatically passed and can be retrieved on the CP using [AttributeValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/attributevalue.html) function.

Comment: Okay, so something simple like this on CloudPage?

`%%[
set @subscriberKey = AttributeValue(_subscriberKey)

]%%
%%=v(@subscriberKey)=%%`

That's currently giving me a 500 error. Is there anything else I would need to do attribute wise?

Comment: @AustinScholl try to uncheck the track click option before you send out the email, and put the attribute value function like this `AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") `

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: @AustinScholl - Please remember to mark my answer as accepted, if it has been helpful

Comment: How do I do that? I haven't seen that option.

Comment: @AustinScholl - you can see how, in [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/602941)